# How to enable scrolling when input panel is open in windows phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am developing an application for windowns phone 7. On the screen I have 4-5 text boxes and at the end I have created one button. Now when I enter data for first text box, input panel gets opened. Now unless and until I close the panel,  I can not scroll further. I want the functaniolality that even when the panel is open I can scroll and can click the last button.

Note: I am creating all the controls at runtime. Controls are not created by drag and drop the control from tool box.

Answer (score 0):

Put controls into `ScrollViewer`. When `TextBoxex` will be in scroll panel, you can scroll them up and down without closing a SIP.

Comment: I have already created text boxes in scroll viewer. And the scroll viewer height is set to screen height. If I decrease the height when input panel is open, and restore the height when input panel is closed, then i can scroll. But this works only when text boxes is in upper half of the screen, for the text boxes in lower half of screen, nothing is displayed, if i try to do this.  Any idea how to handle this??

Comment: Workaround: when user pressed a `Enter` - move focus to next `TextBox`